# Why doesn't composer recognize psr/simple-cache/src

Tags: php, laravel-5.8, psr-4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThY2C.png)
I have to use composer version 1 in the Laravel Project (5.8 version). If I run the `composer install` command,
In `InstalledVersions.php` line 159:

Package `psr/simple-cache` is not installed
An error occurs.
However, `psr/simple-cache` actually exists in the vendor directory.
I deleted the vendor directory and tried reinstalling it. No way. How to fix?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mF77F.png)
composer update

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3",
        "ext-curl": "*",
        "ext-gd": "*",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "ext-mongodb": "^1.5",
        "ext-pcntl": "*",
        "ext-redis": "*",
        "barryvdh/laravel-cors": "^0.11.2",
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.2",
        "bensampo/laravel-enum": "^1.16",
        "cybercog/laravel-optimus": "^3.3",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.6",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~4.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "gabrielelana/byte-units": "^0.5.0",
        "geoip2/geoip2": "^2.9",
        "google/apiclient": "^2.2",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "*",
        "hmazter/laravel-schedule-list": "^1.0",
        "intervention/image": "^2.7",
        "jackiedo/timezonelist": "^5.0",
        "jenner/redis_sentinel": "^0.3.0",
        "jenssegers/agent": "^2.6",
        "jenssegers/mongodb": "3.5.*",
        "jenssegers/mongodb-sentry": "1.0.*",
        "jenssegers/mongodb-session": "1.2.*",
        "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
        "laravel/horizon": "^2.1",
        "laravel/passport": "^7.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "lcobucci/jwt": "3.3.*",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^1.0",
        "league/iso3166": "^2.1",
        "league/uri": "^5.3",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.0",
        "martinlindhe/laravel-vue-i18n-generator": "^0.1.28",
        "monospice/laravel-redis-sentinel-drivers": "^2.4",
        "php-amqplib/php-amqplib": "^2.7",
        "phpseclib/mcrypt_compat": "^1.0",
        "pusher/pusher-php-server": "^3.0",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "^2.9",
        "torann/geoip": "^1.0",
        "ytake/laravel-fluent-logger": "^3.1",
        "zircote/swagger-php": "^3.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.4",
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.2",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "^3.2",
        "themsaid/laravel-langman": "^1.3"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "files": [
            "app/Support/helpers.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried updating your composer to version 2 by running

```
composer self-update
```

I managed to solve the issue by updating composer. Suspect something is deprecated for composer 1